# Как исправить ajax, отправка формы без перезагрузки?

Tags: php, ajax

Здравствуйте помогите исправить обработчик, я незнаю как правильно задать вопрос 
обясню есть форма отправки и все работает все отправляет а вот как очисчать заполненые поля после , а то кажется что форма не оправлена и кликают по несколько раз.

```
                  <div id="erconts"></div>
                <form name="form" id="callbacks"  action='' method='POST'>  
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do">
            <input id="validator" type="text" name="validator" >
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><input name="name" type="text" class="textfield" placeholder="   Ваше Имя и Фамилия"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td align="center"><textarea type="text" name="chat" class="textarea" placeholder="   Ваше сообщение"/></textarea></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>

          <td align="center"  ><input type="submit" value="Оправить" id="btncontcall"  class="button" /></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
       </form>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#btncontcall').click(function(){ 
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"modules/chat_send.php", // Адрес обработчика
         data:$('#callbacks').serialize(),
         error:function(){$("#erconts").html("Произошла ошибка!");},
        beforeSend: function() {
             $("#erconts").html("Отправляем данные...");
         },
        success: function(result){
            $('#erconts').html(result);
            checkThis();
        }
     });
     return false;
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  success: function(result) {
    $('#callbacks')[0].reset();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 success: function(result) {
    $("input").val("");
    $("textarea").val("");
```

Comment: Если так делать исчезает кнопка отправить

Comment: $("input[name=name]").val("");